# Is it possible to get money from user to Marketplace admin and Seller account with stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Currently I am using stripe to charge a amount from user and can get the amount instantly.

Now I have a Marketplace where Chef can add their menus and user can buy it. When user buy the menu I (Marketplace Admin) will charge 10%. For e.g;

Chef Menu Price is = $100
User buy it with $100
I will charge 10% of $100.

So finally Marketplace Admin will receive $10 and Chef will received $90.

My Questions is this possible will Stripe.com ? If so how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with Stripe Connect. You can find more information here:

- https://stripe.com/connect
- https://stripe.com/docs/connect
- https://support.stripe.com/questions/considerations-for-platforms-using-connect